# Trace URL's that link to my iframe/widget

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mysql, iframe

I have created a widget.html page with, for example, a "Powered by Example.com"  box/widget. And I have an HTML iframe that links to that specific page (widget.html) on my site.

```
<iframe src="http://example.com/widget.html"></iframe>
```

I share that iframe code with website owners who want to use my widget on their sites.

I want to be able to see every single site that uses my iframe. I would prefer a code that creates a txt file or even a MySQL Table with all websites URLs that use my widget on their websites.

I basically want to track the sites that use my widget as an iframe . How do I do that? With Javascript? PHP? MySQL?

P.S. I'm not sure if an iframe is the best way to link widgets off my site, but I'm open for your suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1. use jquery
2. then load a request page throgh jquery like : `$("#div1").load("demo_test.txt");`
3. and send a request uri parameter to it
4. you will find the current url using the widget and alos you can get the parameter